# How can I allow users to add existing pictures from Facebook to my site?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to allow users to "import" their existing pictures to my social network. How can I do this? With an array? I actually want them saved on the server, and I'm new to the facebook apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access user's photos you will need to ask for authentication for access the pictures. [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) you will find detail about permission list. Also you can access any album if it is public. To get albums for user http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/.
BTW I think saving user's photos will violate facebook platform policy. Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Tapos

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the profile picture of a user from Facebook by doing a simple GET on the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<username>/picture
```

Read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: What do I do with the URL though? Sorry I'm having trouble grasping the concept. (e.g. <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/its.pete.allport/picture"> but with multiple pictures.) Thanks

Comment: @Pete Didn't quite get you. If you want *all* the photographs that a user has, then look at Tapos' answer.